# Java use of object to hold state does not seem to be working

Tags: java, oop

I'm writing a utility class that should be able to parse delimited files (comma, pipe, colon delimited). It reads a particular line and needs to extract the most commonly used delimiter in that line. But this doesn't seem to be working as expected. When I call the `getHeader()` method in my main method caller class, It seems like the only delimiter that's being acknowledged is a comma from the line. I think its my weak java and oop lacking skills preventing me from understanding the issue. Please advice. Thank you in advance. Below is my code:

```
    public class Parser {
    // sample line of data
    String line = "There|is|data,in,this:file|hause";

    private static class Delimiters {
        static char DEFAULT = ',';
        static char COMMA = ',';
        static char SEMI = ';';
        static char PIPE = '|';
        static char COLON = ':';
    };

    public String[] getHeader() {
        char delim = findDelimiter(line);
        System.out.println("Header delim: " + delim);
        String[] columns = line.split(String.valueOf(delim));
        return columns;
    }

    // figure out the delimiter of the file. This method
    // gets called on lines of file data
    public char findDelimiter(String line) {
        Delimiter dim = new Delimiter();
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            for (char delim : Arrays.asList(Delimiters.COLON, Delimiters.COMMA,
                    Delimiters.PIPE, Delimiters.SEMI)) {
                if (delim == line.charAt(i)) {
                    dim.increaseDelimiterCnt(delim);
                }
            }
        }

        final char theLinesDelimiter = dim.mostCommonDelimiter();
        return theLinesDelimiter;
    }

    private class Delimiter {
        Map<Character, Integer> delimiterCounts = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        private void increaseDelimiterCnt(char delim) {
            System.out.println(delim);

            int value = (delimiterCounts.containsKey(delim) ? delimiterCounts
                    .get(delim) : 0);
            delimiterCounts.put(delim, value++);
            System.out.println(getDelimiterCounts());
        }

        private Map<Character, Integer> getDelimiterCounts() {
            return delimiterCounts;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the delimiter based on greatest frequency of first line in file.
         * 
         * @return String
         */
        private char mostCommonDelimiter() {
            char theDelimiter = ',';
            System.out.println(delimiterCounts);
            int maxValueInMap = (Collections.max(delimiterCounts.values()));
            for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : delimiterCounts
                    .entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue().equals(maxValueInMap)) {
                    theDelimiter = entry.getKey();
                }
            }
            return theDelimiter;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: For starters, you're iterating over the string multiple times unnecessarily. Instead, create an `int` array of the same size as the enum and just increment the corresponding entry.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You can actually do this in 2 lines, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is in this line:

```
            delimiterCounts.put(delim, value++);
```

`++` after a variable-name is a *post*-increment, so although `value++` increments `value`, it still *evaluates* to the original value. So, the above is equivalent to this:

```
            delimiterCounts.put(delim, value);
            value = value + 1; // pointless, since we never use value again
```

Instead you should write:

```
            delimiterCounts.put(delim, value + 1);
```

Your debugging output actually should have been enough to tell you this; it shows you that every delimiter in `delimiterCounts` gets mapped to zero.

I suggest you read [Eric Lippert's blog post, "How to debug small programs"](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You will probably find it useful for the future.

(Note: after fixing the above issue, you'll have another problem. Your program will now correctly identify `|` as the delimiter, but `line.split("|")` does not mean what you want. To fix that one, you'll want to use `Pattern.quote`. I'll let you figure out the details.)

---

**Edited to add:** Since you have concerns about your OOP, I should also say something about the overall design. You may be able to create a more robust and efficient design by using an enumeration:

```
public enum Delimiter {
    COMMA(','), SEMI(';'), PIPE('|'), COLON(':');

    public final char c;
    public final Pattern pattern;

    private DelimiterChar(final char c) {
        this.c = c;
        this.pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(Character.toString(c)));
    }
}
```

You can then use `Delimiter.values()` when you need to enumerate over the possible delimiters, and can use an `EnumSet<Delimiter, Integer>` to store the counts by delimiter.

Note that I've used the name `Delimiter` for something very different than you have. Your `Delimiter` class should probably be called `DelimiterCounter`, since its instances count delimiters, rather than themselves delimiting anything.

Comment: Thanks. Why doesn't line.split("|") work? Isn't that what split is used for? Splits the data out and puts into an array by separating on "|"

Comment: @TazMan: You have read [the Javadoc for `String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: Yes. This is really what I'm doing. For splitting on colon this is how it should be` :  { "boo", "and", "foo" } ` and in the other example they give, this is how I would expect to split on "o".
`o  { "b", "", ":and:f" }`

Comment: @TazMan: Yup, exactly, because `":"` is a regex matching a single colon, and `"o"` is a regex matching a single lowercase O. However, `"|"` is *not* a regex matching a single pipe character. You should probably read through [the Javadoc for `java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), or just Google for "regex tutorial".

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations. I have attempted to expand on this exercise to not only just be a parser method but something I can use to practice my OOP design skills. Would you say this is a pathetic design apart from the bad naming of the DelimiterCounter? Thanks again

Comment: Also, why did you add the final keyword as the char argument to the enum constructor?

Comment: @TazMan: Re: is this "a pathetic design": It's not very OOP-ish. Whether that makes it "pathetic" depends on how strongly you feel that everything should be OOP-ish. For such a small program, I don't think it matters much. Re: `final` keyword: I use it pervasively throughout my code. (And I knew I would like my current team at work when I saw that its coding standards mandated its use.) Fields and variables that never change are easier to reason about, and adding `final` is an indication that never-changing is guaranteed. I always notice when a field or variable is *not* marked as `final`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `findDelmiter` method is broken.  And, it's all one character's fault.

`String#split` parses its arguments as a regular expression.  The pipe character has special meaning in regex; that is, it is used to denote a branching match.

If you want to use a *literal* pipe, you have to escape it.  You can't do that in a single character literal (as escaping only has contextual meaning for a `String`, not a `char`.

Why not just use a regular expression for the split method entirely?  Let's not worry about picking out which one we used *there*, when we could rebuild that if need be.

Here's a snippet.

```
String[] columns = line.split(",|;|\\||:");
```

That complicated-looking regex is actually using the pipe character to branch - it will split on either a comma, a semi-colon, a pipe (properly escaped), or a colon.

I admire the fact that you're using a helper class to determine the counts of your delimiters.  But, you would want to be careful about how you insert into the map - be sure that the key exists first, and if it *does*, pull the current value out of it, and add one to it, then put it back.

Here's a snippet.

```
private static void placeIntoMap(final Map<Character, Integer> counts, final char c) {
    if(counts.containsKey(c)) {
        counts.put(c, counts.get(c) + 1);
    } else {
        counts.put(c, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Curious why do you admire that fact that I'm using a helper class? Is this a sign of hope for my future design skills that may become better contrary to how pathetic they are currently? thanks for the help

Comment: I admire it in the sense that you're trying to abstract it out; I abhor it in the sense that it's a throwaway map container.  But either solution works for now.  When you get into the field, you'll iterate on design principles like this very often.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `split` to count the number of strings you get back. Just subtract 1 because the number of dividers is always 1 less then the number of parts.

```
public class Parser {

    static String line = "There|is|data,in,this:file|hause";
    private static final String[] DELIMS = {",", ";", "\\|", ":"};
    private static Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (String delim : DELIMS)
            count.put(DELIMS[i], line.split(DELIMS[i]).length - 1);
    }
}
```